# Input contains Nan with Tfidf vectorizer output

Tags: python, regression, vectorization

I've got a problem with the output of Tfidf Vectorizer and I've test many solutions given in other topics and nothing works.

I have a csv with two columns : one column test containing ... text and a column score. 
And I want to be able to predict a new score based on a text I will be able to input. 
I think the better solution is to use a linear regression based on tfidf analys on the text.

My code is the following :

```
datas = pandas.read_csv('Data/gucci-account- 
prediction.csv',delimiter=';')
datas['score'] = datas['retweets'] + datas['likes']
import re

def tokenizer(text):
    if text:
        result = re.findall('[a-z]{2,}', text.lower())
    else:
        result = []
    return result

X = datas['text'].values
y = datas['score'].values
vect = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenizer,stop_words='english',dtype=np.float32)
X_train = vect.fit_transform(X)
lr = Ridge(alpha=1.0)
lr.fit(X_train,y)
```

And I have the following error : Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

I already verified and my dataframe ( before vectorization ) contains no nan value so I don't understand why my X matrix would contain any nan or infinite value.

Would you have a solution so it works ? Thank you

Comment: Please, add more information on the stack track (_which_ line rises the error would be useful)